# How do you get the view coordinates of a CListCtrl in LVS_REPORT style on Win XP

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I'm trying to coordinate the scrolling of a CListCtrl with another control. Contrary to the documentation on Win 7 you can call `CListCtrl::GetViewRect` or `CListCtrl::GetOrigin` to get the viewable area coordinates.

e.g. If you're scrolled 10 units across `CListCtrl::GetOrigin`will return x=10, y=0.

Unfortunately Win XP does follow the SDK documentation which says *"... if the control is in report view, the return value is always zero"*.

I'm sure this must be really simple but whats the best way to get the top left coordinates of a CListCtrl viewable area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that GetScrollInfo will do the trick. The nPos value matches the window coordinates (ie the min/max range represents the total size of columns not a fixed 0-100 range).